# I don't get it Glib source codes related to part creating GType && TypeInfo structure

Tags: c, glib, typeinfo

I'm not good at C, but have to use recently. 
while looking GLib codes about 'GType', I can't figure out how this works.

First of all, let me show you codes.

```
//--- GType.c in glib ---
<!-- language: c -->
static TypeNode*
type_node_any_new_W (TypeNode*pnode,GType ftype,const gchar* name,
GTypePlugin* plugin, GTypeFundamentalFlags type_flags)
{
    guint n_supers;
    GType type;
    TypeNode *node;
    guint i, node_size = 0;

    n_supers = pnode ? pnode->n_supers + 1 : 0;
    if (!pnode)
        node_size += SIZEOF_FUNDAMENTAL_INFO;/* fundamental type info*/
    node_size += SIZEOF_BASE_TYPE_NODE ();        /* TypeNode structure */
    node_size += (sizeof (GType) * (1 + n_supers + 1)); /* self + ancestors + (0) for ->supers[] */
    node = g_malloc0 (node_size);
  if (!pnode)                         /* offset fundamental types */
    {
      node = G_STRUCT_MEMBER_P (node, SIZEOF_FUNDAMENTAL_INFO);
      static_fundamental_type_nodes[ftype >> G_TYPE_FUNDAMENTAL_SHIFT] = node;
      type = ftype;
    }
  else
    type = (GType) node;

  g_assert ((type & TYPE_ID_MASK) == 0); // <--- Can't understand.  

  node->n_supers = n_supers;

  ...
  ...
```

If what I thought was right, when the variable node(= TypeNode*) contains  returned void* from g_malloc(), its dereferenced values would be all 0.

As you can see, GType (actually typedef of gsize) was assigned to node which was pointing that allocated heap memory mentioned above. 
 So type' value will be determined at runtime. just one of an memory addresses.

But,

```
 g_assert ((type & TYPE_ID_MASK) == 0);
```

This line makes be embarrasment a little. Because TYPE_ID_MASK statemented "((GType) ((1 << G_TYPE_FUNDAMENTAL_SHIFT) - 1))", it's 3. 000...0011

But, isn't there possibility to the end of 2 bit of type's value were both 0s?

Please save a poor c++ developer :)
Thanks in advance.